# Why is my variable null only in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing a request to TheMovieDb, and am trying to display the result on the same page.

home.html.erb

```
<h1>Welcome here</h1>

<%= form_tag(root_path, remote: true, :controller => "pages", :action => 
"home", :method => "get", :class => "form") do %>
    <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Search", :class => "submit") %>
<% end %>

<% if @result %>
    <%= puts @result %>
    <div><%= @result %></div>
<% end %>


<script type="text/javascript">
  document.querySelector('.form').addEventListener('submit', () => {
      console.log('<%= @result.to_json %>');
  });
</script>
```

pages_controller.rb

```
def home
    require 'uri'
    require 'net/http'

    @search = params[:q]

    url = URI("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=my_api_key&query=#{@search}")

    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
    request.body = "{}"
    response = http.request(request)

    if response.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess) === true
        @result = JSON.parse(response.read_body)
        puts @result
        render json: @result
    end
end
```

I don't understand why my variable is equal to null in the view while I can see the result in my console.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sound strange. Try assign a string to `@result`, just to see if is passed properly to view. Then try pass `JSON.parse(response.read_body).size`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I passed a string value to @result and it's not passed to view. But if i assign string to my variable out of the if statement, the value is passed to the view.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking "why my `@result` is not populated here, after I submit the form and render that json response?"

```
  document.querySelector('.form').addEventListener('submit', () => {
      console.log('<%= @result.to_json %>');
  });
```

And the answer is: because `@result` doesn't exist after page is rendered. Inspect your generated html ("view page source" in the browser). You'll see this there.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.querySelector('.form').addEventListener('submit', () => {
      console.log('null');
  });
</script>
```

Take a look at this guide, should clear some confusion: [Working with Javascript in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#a-simple-example).